# Can't compare two string from extension methods in C#

Tags: c#, string, compare, extension-methods, string-comparison

I created a string extension method

```
 public static string ShortID(this string id)
 {
     return id.Substring(5);
 }
```

When I want to compare two strings using this extension method like this

```
if(Id.ShortID == IdDest.ShortID)
```

I have an error :

```
 CS0019: impossible to apply operator == to operands of type "group of methods" and "group of methods"
```

I don't understand why, because this extension method returns a string so logically I could compare the results as strings no ?

Comment: If you don't use parentheses after the method name, it's just a method group name, not an actual method invocation. See duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add parentheses to have method calls

```
if(Id.ShortID() == IdDest.ShortID())
```